What's the meaning of the last part of this passage?
在 《影》 的写意镜头里，中国文化符号是晕染竹林烟雨，是八卦太极阴阳，其中的极致反差对比与冷凝窒息感，将片中角色的情感外化与人物的情绪内收双线合一.
I don't understand the meaning of "其中的极致反差对比与冷凝窒息感，将片中角色的情感外化与人物的情绪内收双线合一". Could somebody please explain?

It is like a bad writer tried too hard to sound profound. Using incoherent grammar as if he is trying to confuse readers. Simply put, I have no idea what this guy is talking about

a typical management speak - “needlessly obscure or, alternatively, used to disguise an absence of information” https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporate_jargon

Quote:- " I don't understand the meaning of "其中的极致反差对比与冷凝窒息感，将片中角色的情感外化与人物的情绪内收双线合一" You mean you understand the other part?  If so, please let us have your take?

This was my original translation (it has to be said that I originally translated the passage directly to italian, so it might not sound very fluid in english)
In Shadow's shots, which recall ink and water paintings, Chinese cultural symbols are portrayed by the drizzle of the soft-edged bamboo forest and by the images of Yin and Yang and the Eight Trigrams

Since recently we have discussions on AI, here's what Mr. AI has to say about the passage:-
"The provided text is a Chinese passage that describes the use of Chinese cultural symbols in the film "Shadow" (影). The passage highlights the evocative cinematography of the film, which employs traditional Chinese imagery to convey the characters' complex emotions and the film's overall atmosphere.
Key Points:
Chinese Cultural Symbols: The passage mentions two prominent Chinese cultural symbols:
Bamboo Forest in Misty Rain: This imagery evokes a sense of tranquility and beauty, yet it also hints at hidden dangers and lurking mysteries, reflecting the characters' inner turmoil and the film's underlying tension.
Bagua Taiji Yin Yang: This symbol represents balance, harmony, and the interconnectedness of opposing forces, mirroring the dualities and contradictions at play in the film's narrative.
Visual Contrast and Emotional Intensity: The passage emphasizes the juxtaposition of contrasting visual elements, such as the lush bamboo forest and the dark, oppressive interiors, which heighten the emotional intensity of the film.
Externalization and Internalization of Emotions: The passage suggests that the film's visual storytelling effectively externalizes the characters' inner emotions while simultaneously conveying their suppressed feelings.
Overall Interpretation:
The passage highlights the film's masterful use of Chinese cultural symbols and visual contrast to create a rich and evocative cinematic experience. The interplay of these elements amplifies the emotional depth of the characters and the film's overall atmosphere, immersing the audience in a world of intrigue, conflict, and profound human drama"
End
I thought that's pretty good?

Yeah, it does clarify it by a lot. Thanks!

Just to show how "powerful" AI is, "It" came up with that answer in less than 5 seconds. No human, however learned in the Chinese language, could do that. So, be afraid, be very afraid.

My interpretation (of the "not so good writing):

在 《影》 的写意镜头里，中国文化符号 是晕染竹林烟雨，是八卦太极阴阳，其中的极致反差对比 - the sharp/extreme contrast of 晕染竹林烟雨 and 八卦太极阴阳.

将片中角色的情感外化 与 人物的情绪内收 双线合一 - it weaved the primary character's two (opposite) personalities - "unrestrained affection" yet "reserved emotion", into one string (the film).


Note the "opposite personalities" in the 2nd sentence echoes the "contrasting Chinese cultural symbols" in the first.
